# Two Table Comparison in HIVE

Tags: hive

I have two different set of tables. I want to compare the total count in both tables and want to display whether the two tables counts are matching or not. If matching, then 'Pass' else 'fail'.

```sql
SELECT (SELECT COUNT (*)
          FROM Table1  t1
               INNER JOIN Table2 t2
                   ON TRIM (t1.mgac_ac_id) = TRIM (t2.account))
           AS cnt1,
       (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM t3) AS cnt2            where cnt1=cnt2;
```

Above show code is incorrect. Could anyone help on code. Whether want to create any variables in HIVE?

Answer (score 1):

OK, it's simple to complete this. like below:

```
select 
    case when tmp1.value = tmp2.value then 'Pass' else 'Fail' end as result
from
    (select count(1) as value from table1) tmp1
join
    (select count(1) as value from table2) tmp2 on 1=1
```